# Visual Studio 2015 UWP Debugging. Leave installed UWP app intact

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I would like to debug a UWP app without installing over the currently installed version from the Windows Store.

This is what Visual Studio 2015 shows me. I actually want to debug, but not overwrite.

> The app "______" is already installed on this machine.
>
> If you continue with the current deployment, the existing app will be
>   uninstalled and the app's current state will be deleted.

To clarify, I want to debug the version I'm working on in VS, not the version of the app in the Store.

Comment: I'm not sure, but a bet you can do `Debug->Attach to process`. The trick is that your code should match the code that has been deployed to the store

Comment: @j0ey_wh It's the deployment that's the problem. VS deploys over the app from the Store. To clarify, I want to debug the version I'm working on in VS, not the version of the app in the Store.

Comment: @ClaroMendoza then i don't get what's the problem

Comment: try change the package name in the AppManifest

Comment: An app is identified through it's `<Identity>` (see [How to create a basic package manifest for Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211475.aspx) for more information). If you want to deploy a debug version without overwriting the local installation of the same app deployed from the Store, you'll have to (temporarily) change it's `<Identity>`.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the project ID or name information was saved in the [package file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211474.aspx) of UWP, during debugging, it will check the package file(project ID or name or others), if it has deployed before, it would uninstall previous version by design, you can change projectID or others, but it would be a new app.

A workaround is that you could use the remote debugging tool, so you could deploy it to the remote test machine which will not impact your previous version.

Comment: @Carlo Mendoza，any update？ Would you mind letting me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I am also looking for an eloquent solution to this question, LOST's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927615/uwp-visual-studio-how-to-make-different-builds-variants) seems good, though I do not know yet where to put that code